# Pyspark: correlated column is not allowed in predicate

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with three columns `EVENT`, `TIME`, and `PRICE. For all events I would like to aggregate on previous events, for simplicity we'll assume it is mean.

What I would like to do is the following,

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*), MEAN(ti.PRICE)
    FROM table_1 ti
    WHERE ti.EVENT = to.EVENT AND ti.TIME < to.TIME
    ), EVENT

FROM table_1
```

though if I run this in a pyspark environment or pyspark.sql(query) I get the error *correlated column is not allowed in predicate*.

Now, I wonder how I can change either the query to run without errors, or, how I can use native pyspark functions (F.filter....) to achieve the same result.

read other stackoverflow, that did not help

Comment: I think you can use join first, then group by, then calculate statistics like count, mean

Comment: Hi, join on what and then what should I group by on? Thanks!